# Redis default password

Tags: password, configuration, redis

I am trying to maintain a Redis instance running on a Ubuntu server. I explicitly set no password and turned the protected mode off. Yeah it is dangerous, but it is exactly what I need.

The Redis instance works perfectly and I am pretty happy with it, but not for long. In time every single query to Redis starts to fail with `NOAUTH`.

It looks really silly because I cannot even restart Redis for the same reason: `NOAUTH`. Server seems to ask for a password which was never set in the config. WAT. I checked. Then I double checked. No password is set in the config. Yet `NOAUTH`.

I am not very good at Linux administration, and I am totally lost at the moment. Searching Google is not useful. I don't even know what to search.

How should I approach to the problem?